# Remove a dict from a json file, with an input

Tags: python, json

I have this json file

**mat.json**

```
[
    {"navn": "Traktor_ma1", "y": 5, "kp": 10000},
    {"navn": "Bil_ma2", "y": 20, "kp": 100000},
    {"navn": "Gummiged_ma3", "y": 60, "kp": 250000}
]
```

And I need a function to delete one of the line. I have a function that makes it possible to get the "navn" in a enumerated list:

```
def aktiv_remove_mat():
    import json
    f = open("/Users/maltheschroderjakobsen/Downloads/projekt/mat.json",)
    f = json.load(f)
    mat_aktiver = []
    for dct in f:
        if "navn" in dct:  # the elements are dicts!
            mat_aktiver.append(dct["navn"])
    for index, item in enumerate(mat_aktiver, start=1):
        print(index, item)

    input_index = int(input('Choose an item by inputting a number 1-{}: '.format(len(mat_aktiver))))
```

This will make a output like this:

```
Vælg det anlægsaktiv der skal fjernes ("Choose which one")
1 Traktor_ma1
2 Bil_ma2
3 Gummiged_ma3
Skriv tallet på ønsket anlægsaktiv: ("Write the number on which you would pick")
```

As an example I will put in 3.

And then I need to make a function that deletes the whole dict when you pick, here 1-3. So after this the new dict will be:

**mat.json**

```
[
    {"navn": "Traktor_ma1", "y": 5, "kp": 10000},
    {"navn": "Bil_ma2", "y": 20, "kp": 100000}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of items `f` from which you want to remove a dictionary. To remove an item from a list based on the index, you can use a `pop` method.

Important to remember is that indexes in Python begin from 0. If your input is going to start from 1 then you must reduce 1 from the input that is received:

```
f.pop(input_index-1)
```

Just add this line at the end of your code and it will remove the item you want

To write this back to file, you need to do json.dump:

```
with open('/Users/maltheschroderjakobsen/Downloads/projekt/mat.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(f, outfile)
```

Comment: But if I run the code again, it will do the iteration through json and it is still there ? because the functions appends from the json file every time I am running the program

Comment: For that, you just need to dump it back to file. I added that piece of code @MaltheSchrøder

Comment: Where do I put that @Caldazar?  - thank u so much !

Comment: At the end... After you select index, you do the pop and after that you just add this piece of code to do the dump @MaltheSchrøder

Comment: yea it kinda work now, but now my json file is almost empty only showing two names and not the other stuff like y key and value and kp key and value @Caldazar

Comment: If you're using `f` as you put in your code in question, it should have all the details... Unless somewhere in your code you do not put some new values in `f`. Maybe you overwrote it with `mat_aktiver` somewhere? @MaltheSchrøder